¡Cómo conecto postgress que esta en aws a typeorm?
import { DataSource } from "typeorm";
import { Record } from "../entities/Record.entities";

export const appDataSources = new DataSource({
    type: "postgres",
    host: process.env.DATABASE_HOST,
    port: 5432,
    username: process.env.USER,
    password: process.env.PASSWORD,
    database: "records",
    entities: [Record],
    logging: true,
    synchronize: true,
}); 

Así es como tengo el código para conectarme a la base que esta en rds de aws, pero mme arroja el siguiente error
error: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "mi ip", user "", database "records", no encryption
Ayuda, llevo más de 5 horas buscando como resolver esto

Parece que el valor process.env.DATABASE_HOST, que proviene de una variable de entorno, tiene el valor "mi ip". ¿Es éste el nombre del servidor de bases de datos?
